# ¿Por que no funciona qobject_cast en esta clase?

Tags: c++, qt

Esta es la clase...creo que no omito nada importante:

```
 class CambiaValorCommand : public QUndoCommand
 {

 public:
     CambiaValorCommand(const QModelIndex &indiceAntiguo, const QModelIndex &indiceNuevo, const QVariant &value, MiModel* m, QString
     descripcion, QUndoCommand* parent = nullptr);

     void undo();
     void redo();

     int LeeFila() const;
     int LeeColumna() const;
private:
 (...)     
 }
```

Y luego:

```
const QUndoCommand* com = nullptr;
        if (pila->count()-1>=0)
        {
            com = pila->command(pila->count()-1);
        }
        const CambiaValorCommand* com1 = dynamic_cast<const CambiaValorCommand*>(com);//funciona

        //const CambiaValorCommand* com1 = qobject_cast<const CambiaValorCommand*>(com);//NO funciona
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta declarar la macro `Q_OBJECT`. El contenido de esta macro no es heredable y, sin ella, el objeto no posee los metadatos necesarios para diversas funcionalidades de Qt, como las señales o esta función.

```
class CambiaValorCommand : public QUndoCommand
{
  Q_OBJECT // <-----
};
```

Comment: Pensaba que no era necesario al venir por herencia de una clase que sí incluye la macro. Todo aclarado y muchas gracias